# Conditional Formatting entire worksheet with case sensitive text

Tags: excel, case-sensitive, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel worksheet that I would like to use conditional formatting on to change text color. The problem that I am having is that it uses genetics so I need formatting to be case sensitive. Ie:

```
dd=red
Dd=yellow
DD=green
```

Right now I am using conditional formatting > format cell that contains > specific text. That isn't case sensitive so anything with two d's in it, regardless of case, turns the color red. I tried to google and found a few things:

1) use "exact" which when I did this said it was incorrect. I tried same as above but used

```
=EXACT("dd")
```

instead of just `dd`. It tells me to use a valid formula.

2) version 2003, which is the only option I have at work, isn't case sensitive compatible - is this true and if so is it easy to figure out how to define that I want case sensitive in newer versions?

3) use a macro

Am I just SOL with my old version of Excel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the option "use a formula" and enter

```
=EXACT(A1,"dd")
```

where `A1` is the first cell in the area where you're applying your CF